# Forma alterna de "deberá indicársele un asiento libre y sanitizado para que tome asiento"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Me surge una problemática con el siguiente texto:

> Una vez registrado el pasajero deberá indicársele un asiento libre y sanitizado para que tome asiento.

Ya que se me hace algo repetitivo el utilizar la palabra **asiento**, qué alternativas podría utilizar para que dicho texto sea adecuado o quiero saber si así tal cual es adecuado. Cabe mencionar que esto se está utilizando para un manual de operación.

Comment: "...para que se siente" es una alternativa, pero también suena repetitivo.

Comment: "para sentarse", "para ocupar", "para que ocupe"

Comment: Un detalle: debería colocarse coma después de "el pasajero".

Comment: No encuentro la palabra "sanitizar" ni en el DLE ni en el diccionario de americanismos. ¿Puedo sugerir "higienizar"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El verbo [*ocupar*](https://dle.rae.es/ocupar) parece apropiado, y evita la repetición:

- Una vez registrado el pasajero, deberá indicársele un asiento libre y sanitizado para que lo ocupe.

Como dice Charlie en un comentario (y la [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/desinfectar-no-sanitizar/)), la palabra "sanitizar" no está en el DLE, y una alternativa podría ser *desinfectar*:

- Una vez registrado el pasajero, deberá indicársele un asiento libre y desinfectado para que lo ocupe.

A menos que la palabra "sanitizar" se haya definido en otra parte del manual de operaciones. En ese caso, claramente es mejor no cambiarla.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción más abreviada e igualmente clara podría ser:

- Una vez registrado el pasajero, deberá **asignársele** un asiento libre y sanitizado / un asiento libre e higienizado.

Answer (score 2):

Añadiendo a los comentarios anteriores, yo omitiría el `'para que tome asiento'`, o lo sustituiría por `'para su uso'` o `'para su uso durante el viaje'`